# how to get git log from a repo. in github.com?

Tags: git, github

I know one way to a `git log` is to do a `git clone` of a repo. from somewhere where there is a git repo. So if there is a large git repo. on github.com and I just want a git log of the repo. either between the last release and now or even just a raw git log is it possible without cloning the repo. ? If yes, how do I go about doing that. You can use any git repo. on github to share ways to do the same. I tried on the interwebs if there was any way to do the same but came up short.

Answer (score 4):

You can only do so if the remote server which provide the Git repo hosting service also provides an API.

For instance, GitHub allows you to get the log of a git repo (without cloning it first), with [listing the commits on a repository](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#list-commits-on-a-repository)

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits
```

You can add several parameters to limits the commits you want, like `?sha=xxx`, a SHA or branch to start listing commits from.

Comment: Can you try this as an example with https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent (as to how it will work if we use that repo.) and keep the base as master from 23rd October 2014. I do see the changelog which does what changes has been done on master https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/blob/master/Changelog but still would be good to understand how it all works.

Comment: looking forward to you sharing an example to emulate please.

Comment: What VonC means is you simply do an HTTP get to an api URL of the above form. In the example shirish wants, the resulting full URL is http://api.github.com/repos/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/commits -- which does work if you point your browser to it, but is probably not what you want, since it is listing the commits in a JSON-encoded form, with the comments available via embedded URLs, rather than in an easily human-readable form as in `git log`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use this [Github api endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#compare-two-commits):

> Compare two commits
> GET /repos/:owner/:repo/compare/:base...:head
> Both :base and :head must be branch names in :repo. To compare branches across other repositories in the same network as :repo, use the format :branch. For example:
>
> GET /repos/:owner/:repo/compare/hubot:branchname...octocat:branchname

Comment: It's the same answer as above, please share with an example as I asked maybe taking qbittorrent so I know how it's done precisely and can try at my own end to replicate and see if I get the same results.